# Duplication of cellular phone Android 5.1.1

Tags: google-maps

I think I have been duplicated or hacked. Google Maps time line shows me present for three days consecutively and me amd device were at another location, home. Is this possible what info /action have I allowed if it is possible? What I need to stop or solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

If only one device is on the timeline, there is a high possibility that you GPS is not good.
My device thinks often that I am in a city about 20km away. I is a bug with google.
To get really save, you can open the Android device manager in your web browser and get a list of all Android devices logged in into your account.

Comment: Consider all info in question

Comment: You have written that you ask yourself why Google does have the wrong Position, haven't you?